# Plot a graph using metric information fetched using AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, graph, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have successfully retrieved metrics data of `AWS EC2` service using `AWS Cloudwatch` Java API.

Now I need to show the metrics data as real time streaming and plot the graph. I have never worked in any of the `Java graph library/API`. Can someone suggest how to start? 
Also, should it be a web application where AJAX requests will keep on fetching metrics data?

Answer (score 1):

DIY is fun for sure, but you can use existing tools to collect CloudWatch metrics and present them as real-time portals.

[image: ATSD ec2 console]